In the Saga Pattern, how do microservices listen for compensating events?
I am currently learning microservices and working on implementing the Saga pattern.
To better understand what I need to code, I created a diagram.

There is one point I think I might be missing.
In the last step, when the Shipment Service fails, it throws a "Shipment Failed" event.
The Inventory Service listens for the "Shipment Failed" event and takes action, such as rolling back inventory.
After that, should the Inventory Service throw a "Stock Update Failed" event, or should the Order Service also listen for the "Shipment Failed" event?
In case of a failure, should each service throw its own events one by one, or should only the failed service throw its failure event, with others listening to it?
I am also seeking suggestions on event naming. I am not sure if my current naming conventions are appropriate.

The Saga pattern, abstracted from the technology bias ("microservices" and conflating activities with components), is about independent components communicating asynchronously over designated message queues, i.e. a form of SOA: in particular, it does not tell how to model a domain. For example, if getting the goods back in the warehouse should trigger an order cancellation, then do have an "inventory rolled back" message from Inventory back to Orders. The point being, the details altogether depend on your specific requirements: you must model the underlying workflow with its actual rules.

Good question! This is a design choice but general recommendation is to minimize complexity of your EDA (Event Driven Architecture). Technically, Order Service can listen to any event you configure it including "Shipment Failed" event. However, should you do that? It depends upon at least two parameters:

You want to update the Order service events database first so that it can send notification to the user without waiting for all intermediate transactions rollbacks
You can not only implement this system but also sure that system support team can understand and manage the complexity of event publishers and consumers.

If the answers to both questions is YES then go for it, otherwise NO to keep it sequential and simple...in design, implement and operations (most important)
For event naming, set your own standard but highly recommended to use CloudEvents specification (check out cloudevents.io for details)
Hope this helps. All the best :)

Solution "event storming"
I think this is what you're trying to do :

The first thing is an HTTP request "create order" to the OrderService.
The orderCreated event indicates that an order has been created.
The inventoryUpdated event indicates that the inventory has been updated (by the way, it is either StockService and StockXXX events, or InventoryService and InventoryXXX events, be consistent in the naming of the events).
The shipmentProcessed event indicates the shipment has been successfully made.
The shipmentProcessFailed event indicates a failure in the processing of the shipment (invalid address, ...).
The shipmentCancelled event indicates the shipment has been cancelled (the customer has refused or returned the order).
The inventoryCancelled event indicates the inventory has been rollbacked.
The orderCancelled event indicates the order has been cancelled.


Note: I don't like this kind of architecture. Events are flowing everywhere, and it is very hard to get a picture of the global situation (how many orders in each stage at a given time ?) or of a single command (how to consolidate all the messages relative to an order ?). You will probably end up consolidating all the messages into a big database to monitor the system, and it will double the cost of your project.
Solution "single repository"
I suggest you adopt this kind of architecture, based on a single repository that directly contains a complete representation of an order. When an element of the repository is modified, an event is emitted. All the services receive the message, but only the one concerned by the current state of the order will process it.
Normal flow :

The CreateService verify the order and create it into the repository with the state created.
The repository emits a message with the current state of the order : created.
The InventoryService receives the message and updates the inventory. Then it updates the order into the repository with the state inventoryUpdated.
The repository emits a message with the current state of the order : inventoryUpdated.
The ShipmentService receives the message and proicess the shipment. Then it updates the order into the repository with the state shipmentProcessed.
The repository emits a message with the current state of the order : shipmentProcessed.


If something goes wrong with the inventory, then the scenario is :

The CreateService verify the order and create it into the repository with the state created.
The repository emits a message with the current state of the order : created.
The InventoryService receives the message and try to update the inventory but fails. Tt updates the order into the repository with the state inventoryUpdateFailed.
The repository emits a message with the current state of the order : inventoryUpdateFailed.


If something goes wrong with the shipment, that's the same logic : the Shipmentservice updates the order into the repository with the state shipmentProcessFailed or shipmentCancelled. The InventoryService reacts to those messages by rollbacking the changes and updates the order into the repository.
Note: this approach is not very different from the "event storming" approach, except instead of having messages here and there, you have a single repository that emits messages. The big advantage is that you can query the repository to have a clear view of the situation. You can query how many orders are currently in a given state, or you can query a specific order to see in which state it is. In real world production, this is invaluable.


After that, should the Inventory Service throw a "Stock Update Failed" event, or should the Order Service also listen for the "Shipment Failed" event?
In case of a failure, should each service throw its own events one by one, or should only the failed service throw its failure event, with others listening to it?

A compensating transaction undos the changes in a reserve order as the original changes happened. That means first you should undo the changes in the Inventory Service and then (and only then) you should undo the changes in the Order Service.
So, if you would listen to the "Shipment Failed" event in both services then you could end up in a situation where the Order Service has already undone the changes while the Inventory Service is still struggling to undo previous change. Your compensation transaction might utilize retries to rollback changes.
Minor: Please try to avoid using this wording: throw XYZ event. The verb throw is usually used in the realm of Exceptions. Which could indicate that the transaction is synchronous. But the SAGA by nature is asynchronous. So, I would suggest to use either the emit or the publish word.

I am also seeking suggestions on event naming.

The general rule of thumb is to use past tense in the event names because they should represent a fact (which has already happened). Based on my experience every team has its own preference on the event naming. Like one might prefix event names with the emitter service name. Others might prefer shorter and concise name and use mapping/lookup tables.
It does not matter which one you prefer. What matters is that you should have an agreement and try to be convenient and use that convention everywhere IMHO.

Don't use event-based architecture to implement the SAGA pattern. Maintaining and operating such a brittle architecture is a nightmare for any non trivial scenario.
Use orchestration instead. For example here how your example looks using temporal.io (MIT Open Source License) Java SDK:
  public void fulfillOrder(Order order) {
    // Configure SAGA to run compensation activities in parallel
    Saga.Options sagaOptions = new Saga.Options.Builder().setParallelCompensation(true).build();
    Saga saga = new Saga(sagaOptions);
    try {
      saga.addCompensation(inventoryService::rollbackInventory, order);
      inventory.updateStock(order);

      saga.addCompensation(shipmentService::cancelShipment, order);
      shipmentService.process(order);
    } catch (TemporalFailure e) {
      saga.compensate();
      throw e;
    }
  }

Temporal ensures that even if a process crashes in the middle of this function the execution will be automatically migrated to another machine and continue from the crash point as nothing happened. It guarantees that this function evenutally completes even if each API call takes weeks.
Here is a complete executable sample of a booking SAGA.
